# Move both tracked and untracked files to a subdirectory

Tags: git

I have a git repository containing many files and folders, some of which are tracked in git and others of which are not. I'd like to move everything to a subdirectory (i.e. the result of `mv * subdir/`), but have git recognise that the tracked files have merely been moved. I don't want to have to manually re-add all the repository files to git in their new location.

I've tried some naive possibilities like `git mv * subdir/` (fails because `git mv` won't move untracked files), but can't work out if there is a simple way to achieve this. Can anyone suggest one?

Comment: `git mv * subdir/` for the tracked files, followed by a `mv * subdir/` doesn't work?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann: `git mv * subdir/` moves nothing at all.

Comment: Admittedly as a trick, one can `mv` the untracked files first and `git mv *` afterwards --- but this depends on how easy it is to generalize over the untracked files. (I've only had ignored emacs temp files, which I wanted to keep, so was easy to `mv *~ path/`)

Comment: You all missed the `-k` flag on `git mv`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with a bash one-liner that was simpler than I expected. After running `mv * subdir/`:

```
git status | grep deleted | sed "s/ *deleted: */subdir\//" | xargs git add
```

In case it isn't clear, this just adds everything that was previously in the repo, replacing the old filepath with the new one.

I'd still be interested if there's a more natural way to do this with git. <strike>A disadvantage is that it actually didn't recognise that the files were merely moved, even though their contents were unaltered.</strike>

Edit: And the rename is detected correctly if I also `git rm` the old filepaths.

Comment: Is the `git rm <old filepaths>` to be issued after `git add` in your one-liner and before `git commit`?

Answer (score 6):

There is an easy way to do this with `git mv`:

```
git mv -k SOURCE... DESTINATION
mv -n SOURCE... DESTINATION
```

This will move all of the tracked files first, then untracked files. This will not overwrite anything.

If you want to overwrite:

```
git mv -fk SOURCE... DESTINATION
mv -f SOURCE... DESTINATION
```

The end result preserves the tracked/untracked properties of the files as expected, unlike `mv && git add`

---

For reference, the docs:

`git mv -k`

> Skip move or rename actions which would lead to an error condition. An error happens when a source is neither existing nor controlled by Git, or when it would overwrite an existing file unless -f is given.

`git mv -f` (`git mv --force`)

> Force renaming or moving of a file even if the target exists

`mv -n` (`mv --no-clobber`)

> Do not overwrite an existing file

`mv -f` (`mv --force`)

> Do not prompt before overwriting

Comment: I'm using git 2.34.1 and I only needed the first line 'git mv -k SOURCE DESTINATION' to move both tracked and untracked files on the computer I used to change the repo.  I tried the second command on a different computer that pulled from the updated repo, but because I had subdirectories it didn't work.  I suspect `rsync` would be the way to go for those files, but I didn't need to keep them.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you move the files manually (not using the git command line), then `git rm old-filename` and `git add new-filename`, git will recognise the file has been moved rather than deleted and a new file created.

Comment: Not just in general. If you alter the files after `git mv` too much, Git won't recognize them as moved anymore, just like what happens when you use `mv` + `git rm` + `git add`.

Comment: I can do this manually, but the problem is automating it for everything at once. There are many files, both tracked and untracked, and it seems like there must be a way to move both types with less effort than this.

Answer (score 0):

Git should be able to handle if you just move files into new subdir.

```
mv <list-of-files> <dest>
git add dest
```

`git status` should show already tracked files as renamed.

Comment: This also adds all the currently-untracked files to the git repo. I do not want that (edit: and nor do I want to manually add each tracked filepath to the repo)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

- Manually make a (normal) full copy in the new location
- Call `git mv * subdir/ -f` (note the -f flag) which will update git and overwrite files, though technically makes no difference.
- Manually delete files from old location

Answer (score 0):

Because I sometimes sync binary output files directly between machines instead of putting them under git control, I sometimes need to move untracked files on more than one machine.  I choose one computer to be my 'focus' and the remaining ones are the 'others'

On my focal machine I use

`git mv -k SOURCE TARGET`

This moves all of the files, tracked and untracked.  I then push this to github.

On the other machines I use the following script I call 'rsync.untracked.files' to first move untracked files before pulling from github.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# copy files using rsync that are not indexed by git
# Ignore files under git control
# Don't clobber local files
# Create a record of what happens
#
# example:
#    rsync.exclude.git.ls-files watauga.bio.utk.edu:$(pwd)/Output ./Output

if [[ "$#" -lt 2 ]]; then
    echo "Error in $0:  Minimum of arguments expected: <OPT> SOURCE  TARGET"
    echo "  Example rsync.exclude.git.ls-files -n remote:$(pwd)/Output ./Output ";
    exit 1;
fi

SOURCE="${@:(-2):1}"
TARGET="${@: -1}"
OPTARGS="${@:1:${#}-2}" ## arguments

# Create a tmp file with a list of all files indexed by git
TMPFILE=$(mktemp);
git ls-files > $TMPFILE;
rsync -av $OPTARGS --info=progress2 --exclude-from="$TMPFILE" --log-file="$TMPFILE.log" "$SOURCE" "$TARGET"

rm "$TMPFILE"
echo "rsync session log saved to $TMPFILE.log"
```

So on the other computers I use

```
rsync.untracked.files SOURCE TARGET
git pull
```